# Angular 7: ngsw-worker.js failed to load

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, angular7

### Problem

There is a *universal* app that uses a *Service Worker*.

Recently upgraded from *Angular 6.1* to *7*.

After uploading the updated files to the server getting:

[image]

Details:

`The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
main.2733b77522d2feee4713.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
    at j (polyfills.92108b287fe28032870b.js:1)
    at polyfills.92108b287fe28032870b.js:1
    at polyfills.92108b287fe28032870b.js:1
    at e.invoke (polyfills.92108b287fe28032870b.js:1)
    at Object.onInvoke (main.2733b77522d2feee4713.js:1)
    at e.invoke (polyfills.92108b287fe28032870b.js:1)
    at t.run (polyfills.92108b287fe28032870b.js:1)
    at polyfills.92108b287fe28032870b.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.92108b287fe28032870b.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.2733b77522d2feee4713.js:1)
Sr @ main.2733b77522d2feee4713.js:1
t.handleError @ main.2733b77522d2feee4713.js:1
...
(anonymous) @ main.2733b77522d2feee4713.js:1
The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

### SSL

Using a valid certificate generated by https://letsencrypt.org/.

### Chrome Security

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason was some versions of some packages that don't play together.

My solution was to `ng new` the whole new project and transfer files step by step. After that everything worked as it should (with Angular v7 in place).

Conclusion: check 3 times before update any proj.